# Split a list of timestamps by intervals of 2 seconds in python

Tags: python

I have a list of timestamps all converted to integers. How can I split them into separate lists of 2-second intervals?

```
d = [1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256401, 1499256401, 1499256401, 1499256401, 1499256402, 1499256402, 1499256403, 1499256403, 1499256404, 1499256404, 1499256405, 1499256405, 1499256405, 1499256405, 1499256406, 1499256406, 1499256407, 1499256407, 1499256408, 1499256408, 1499256408, 1499256408, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409]
```

I would like to split them into intervals of 2 seconds so that I am able to print out the results of each interval.

Intended output:

```
[1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256401, 1499256401, 1499256401, 1499256401, 1499256402, 1499256402]
[1499256403, 1499256403, 1499256404, 1499256404, 1499256405, 1499256405, 1499256405, 1499256405]
[1499256406, 1499256406, 1499256407, 1499256407, 1499256408, 1499256408, 1499256408, 1499256408]
[1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post also the code you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop to group items spanning a maximum difference of 2:

```
lst = [[]]
start = d[0]
for x in d:
    if x-start <= 2:
        lst[-1].append(x)
    else:
        lst.append([x])
        start = x
```

If the elements are not sorted, you can call `sorted` to do a presort before grouping.

For code reuse (imports and all that), you can create a grouper class and then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for grouping:

```
from itertools import groupby

class Grouper(object):
    def __init__(self, start=None, diff=2):
        self.diff = diff
        self.start = start
        self._count = 0

    def __call__(self, x):
        if x-self.start > self.diff:
            self._count += 1
            self.start = x
        return self._count
```

And then the grouping is now simplified to:

```
lst = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(d, Grouper(start=d[0]))]
```

---

```
[[1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256401, 1499256401, 1499256401, 1499256401, 1499256402, 1499256402], 
 [1499256403, 1499256403, 1499256404, 1499256404, 1499256405, 1499256405, 1499256405, 1499256405], 
 [1499256406, 1499256406, 1499256407, 1499256407, 1499256408, 1499256408, 1499256408, 1499256408], 
 [1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409]]
```

Comment: Psh. You beat me this time. ;/

Comment: This only works assuming that the elements are sorted in advance

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly for me. Elements are sorted!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this - determine the range of minimum and maximum values of `d` and then check if each element is within the interval if 2 seconds `(x, x+1, x+2)`:

```
for x in range(min(d), max(d)+1, 3):
    print ([item for item in d if item in (x, x+1, x+2) ])
```

Returns:

```
[1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256400, 1499256401, 1499256401, 1499256401, 1499256401, 1499256402, 1499256402]
[1499256403, 1499256403, 1499256404, 1499256404, 1499256405, 1499256405, 1499256405, 1499256405]
[1499256406, 1499256406, 1499256407, 1499256407, 1499256408, 1499256408, 1499256408, 1499256408]
[1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409, 1499256409]
```

Comment: Thank you but the answer is not easily scalable assuming I want to change the intervals to 6000 seconds.